# How do I add a subscriber to a SQL Server Replication Publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

In entering the credentials for the remote server, I get an error asking for the actual server name. What I usually provide is `[IP Address]` as the server name but I get an error asking for the actual server name so I provide `[IP Address]\[ServerName]` but it still does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Replication requires that you use the actual server names in all parts of the setup. In order to find the server name you should be using, do `select @@servername` on each server involved (publisher, distributor, and subscriber).

Comment: but how does the publisher know the name of a remote subscriber if you cannot use an ip/dns address?

Comment: In the interest of full disclosure, I've never had to set up replication in such a topology. But I have tried to use an alias (i.e. a CNAME) and it errors out with the "you have to use the real name" error. But if I were to speculate, I'd say that you can add a linked server with the real name and the target being an IP address. The replication setup will use the linked name, connect using the IP address, and then run the verification and find out that the linked server name and the actual server name match, thus passing the check.